# How to get the maximum length configured in an ActiveRecord validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Given a model:

```
class Person
  validates_lenght_of :name, :maximum => 50
end
```

I have some view code that shows a countdown and enforces this maximum. However I hard coded the number 50 into that view code. Is there a way to extract this number from the model?

Something like:

```
Person.maximum_length_of_name
```

I tried this:

```
Person.validators_on(:name)
 => [#<ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator:0x000001067a9840 @attributes=[:name], @options={:case_sensitive=>true}, @klass=Trigger(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, slug: string, last_update_by: integer)>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x000001067a6c30 @attributes=[:name], @options={}>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator:0x000001067a3f08 @attributes=[:name], @options={:tokenizer=>#<Proc:0x00000101343f08@/Users/sjors/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activemodel-3.0.6/lib/active_model/validations/length.rb:9 (lambda)>, :maximum=>50}>]
```

The information is in there, but I don't know how to extract it:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [validators_on](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validators_on) method

```
irb(main):028:0> p Person.validators_on(:name)[0].options[:maximum]
50
=> 50
```

As @Max Williams mentioned it works only on Rails 3

Comment: This is rails 3 only i think.  Which might not be a problem, Sjors didn't specify :)

Comment: Thanks, I do use Rails 3, but it doesn't work for me. I added the output of Person.validators to my original post.

Comment: In your case it will be `Person.validators_on(:name)[2].options[:maximum]`

Answer (score 13):

The problem with @nash answer is that validators do not own a certain order. I figured out how to do the same thing with just some more code but in some kind of safer mode ('cause you can add more validators later and break the order you get it):

```
(Person.validators_on(:name).select { |v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator }).first.options[:maximum]
```

I think it does only work for Rails 3 too.

Comment: This is a better answer. And for more "Dry way" it's easy to add this method as an ActiveRecord generic one. I explain how in my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

**[Edit 2017-01-17] Carefull** my answer is old (2012) and was for Rails 3. It may not work / be ideal for newer Rails versions.

---

Just to bring a little more DRY spirit, you could create a generic class method to get maximum "length_validator" value on any attribute, like so:

Create a module in your lib directory and make it extend [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

```
module ActiveRecord::CustomMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end

# include the extension 
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecord::CustomMethods)
```

Add the "module ClassMethods" in it and create the "get_maximum" method:

```
module ActiveRecord::CustomMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def get_maximum(attribute)
      validators_on(attribute).select{|v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator}.first.options[:maximum]
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT 1: Configuration**

You'll also have to add a require in one of your initializers.

For instance, here are my configurations:

1. I've put my file in lib/modules/active_record/extensions.
2. I've added this in my autoload_paths: `config.autoload_paths += 
   %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)` *Note: this is not required, but best practice if you want to put there some of your custom classes and modules that you share between your apps.*
3. In one of my initializers (config/initializers/custom.rb) I've added this line: `require "active_record/extensions"`

And that should do it! Restart your server and then...

**END EDIT 1**

And then you should be able to do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area(:body, :maxlength => f.object.class.get_maximum(:body)) #Or just use Comment.get_maximum(:body) %>
<% end %>
```

I hope it will help others! :) Of course you can customize the method the way you want and add options and do fancy stuff. ;-)

Comment: I put the code in **/lib**, set `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and restarted the server, but still I get `undefined method 'get_maximum' for #<Class:0x000000040c7818>`. Anything else that needs to be configured? Filename restrictions?

Comment: Yep, my bad, I forgot to tell that you have to require it in one of your initializers... I'll update my post. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: For some reason it only works for me when I include the filename of the class itself (`require "active_record/extensions/custom_methods"`), which obviously goes without the need for setting the **autoload_path**.

Comment: You really no longer need to add the lib folder to the autoload_path variable? Normally you still have to.... Otherwise Rails won't search for your custom_methods file in this folder, will it?

Comment: The `require` seems to suffice. I am unfamiliar with the idea of the **autoload_path** setting.

Comment: Ok that's good to know! I've put the autoload_path because I have other files in my "modules" folder, some custom modules and classes that I use in my app. I thought it was also required to include some extensions (like for the ActiveRecord class or String class...) but it seems that I was wrong. So thanks for pointing this out! ;)

Answer (score 5):

More concise:

```rb
Person.validators_on(:name).detect { |v| v.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator) }.options[:maximum]
```

Uses `detect{}` instead of `select{}.first` and `is_a?` instead of `class ==`.
That works with Rails 4.1 as well.

Comment: You could use `find` as well, but this way is definitively more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Even more dynamic than Kulgar's answer would be to use something like this:

```ruby
Person.validators_on(attribute)
  .select { |v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::LengthValidator }
  .select { |v| v.options[:maximum].present? }.first.options[:maximum]
```

That way **you can order the validators inside the model the way you want**.

#### Use it as a Rails helper

You then could use this code to write a helper:

```ruby
# Returns the maximum length for a given attribute of a model
def get_maxlength(model, attribute)
  model.validators_on(attribute)
    .select { |v| v.class == ActiveRecord::Validations::LengthValidator }
    .select { |v| v.options[:maximum].present? }.first.options[:maximum]
end
```

And utilize the helper like this:

```ruby
= f.text_field :name, maxlength: get_maxlength(f.object.class, :name) # Or use get_maxlength(Person, :name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an indirect answer, but is an alternative solution, just in case it may prove useful to anyone.

### Alternative Solution 1

```
class Person
  MAX_LENGTHS = {
    name: 50,
    # email: 30, etc...
  }.freeze

  validates :name, length: { maximum: MAX_LENGTHS.fetch(:name) }
end

# usage example in view file
<%= Person.MAX_LENGTHS.fetch(:name) %>
```

### Alternative Solution 2

... or if you prefer one-liners, or to not use a Hash constant

```
class Person
  validates :name, length: { maximum: (MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 50) }
  # validates :password, length: {
  #   minimum: (MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8),
  #   maximum: (MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 70)
  # }
  # ... etc
end

# usage example in view file
<%= Person.MAX_NAME_LENGTH %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in rails 2, it's not easy.  I remember trying this before and not getting far.  You can get at the validation objects but they don't list which field they are for which seemed very odd to me.  People have done plugins for this (ie to inspect or reflect on an AR object's validations), such as https://github.com/redinger/validation_reflection

Answer (score 0):

Kulgar's answer is good and possibly ideal. Here is an easier way to do this for Rails 4 that does not require modifying any configuration, with the disadvantage that you have to add an include line to every model that wants to use it.

models/concerns/introspection.rb:

```
module Introspection

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def max_length(property)
      Resource.validators_on(property.to_sym).
          select{ |v| v.kind_of?(ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator) }.
          first.options[:maximum]
    end
  end

end
```

Then in your model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Introspection
  ..
end
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area(:body, :maxlength => f.object.class.max_length(:body)) %> # Or just use Comment.max_length(:body) %>
<% end %>
```