# rails, retrieve maximum value of validates_length_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a validation on its attribute:

```
validates_length_of :description, :maximum => 1000
```

validation is done on server side, but I would like to add some constraints in the client size by using a jquery limitation plugin on the textarea input corresponding to :description attribute. I have succeded to do this. but I would like to avoid retyping the :maxium value (1000) for the javascript side. 
Is there a way to get that :maxmium value in rails ? to write it in the js part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get at the validations for a given ActiveModel class from the [validators](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validators) property. This returns a list of validator objects. The one you are interested in is a [LengthValidator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/LengthValidator.html), and if you can select the one you are interested in the maximum value is available in the options hash. Here is a crude example:

```
require 'active_record'

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_length_of :title, :maximum => 1000
end

puts MyModel.validators[0].options   # -> {:maximum=>1000}
```

Comment: MyModel.validators_on(:description)[0].options[:maximum]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015001/how-to-get-the-maximum-length-configured-in-an-activerecord-validation

Comment: @Sector - that looks like a better answer

Comment: More compatible would be `MyModel.validators_on(:discription).select{|validator| validator.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator)}.first.options[:maximum]`. But that might be over engineering too.