# Rails: get values from length validator for a field in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I havel a model with validators on some fields. Example:

```
class Notation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_length_of :name, minimum: 5, maximum: 128
end
```

is there a way to get those values from minimum and maximum for the :name field in the template (because I want to show there the value of min and max length to the user, and want to do this dynamically, with the template reflecting the values from the model)?
In the rails console, I can do something like

```
Notation.validators_on(:name)
```

which outputs

```
#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00000005428420 @attributes=[:name], @options={}>, #<ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator:0x0000000541b8d8 @attributes=[:name], @options={:case_sensitive=>true}, @klass=Notation (call 'Notation.connection' to establish a connection)>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator:0x0000000540baf0 @attributes=[:name], @options={:minimum=>5, :maximum=>128}>
```

If I get using the array's index

```
Notation.validators_on(:name)[2]
```

I have:

```
#<ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator:0x0000000540baf0 @attributes=[:name], @options={:minimum=>5, :maximum=>128}>
```

but I was wondering if there is another way, maybe passing the type of validation I'm 'queryng', because I can't rely on the order of the array.

Comment: I think you'll find what you need in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015001/how-to-get-the-maximum-length-configured-in-an-activerecord-validation

Comment: Thanks @SamyKacimi that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

To get the validator, you can filter:

```rb
options = Notation.validators_on(:name)
  .select { |v| v.is_a? LengthValidator }
  .first.options
```

Then you can get `options[:maximum]` etc.

In case there is no such validator, you might have to `rescue` from the code, as otherwise the `first` will fail.